# Changing published mobile application developing language from ionic to flutter

Tags: flutter, ionic-framework, mobile

I have a mobile application developed using Ionic. Now I want to redevelop it in flutter and publish a new update, would that be possible?  will google play and AppStore allow that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no constraint on development language. But,

- You need to use same certificates/keys for iOS App
- You need to use same key-store/keys for Android App
- If you are using local database or file storage, then you should follow the same path in your newly created app as well. If you are using any third-party library to manage the db or file paths, then it may be in different location altogether. (This one actually happened to me. When I migrated my app from a cross-platform framework to Native the database path got changed in release version)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. that make sense. I will do as you say. thanks again

Comment: @KardoAziz You are welcome. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: And if you are using localStorage or Local DB to save any user information i.e: auth token etc then your user need to login again.